# Change selected ComboBox item, from text file string not working

Tags: vb.net

Ok.

So I am working on a project, irrelevant, and I have a bunch (8) of ComboBoxes (they are in DropDownList mode) and there is 8 save files. I have them being imported and converted to strings:

```
Using class2 As New StreamReader(path & "SaveData/classdata/classdata2.NIC")
        Dim fdcount1 As String
        fdcount = class2.ReadToEnd()
        MessageBox.Show(fdcount1)
        hr2choice.SelectedItem = fdcount1
    End Using
```

I already tested this, and it seems to be working.

(Test code I used:)

```
MessageBox.Show(fdcount1)
```

and it showed the value ("DiVita")

Despite this, when I tried setting the ComboBox value to this, it did not seem to work.
The ComboBox does have this value in it, and if I try this, it works:

```
hr2choice.SelectedItem = "DiVita"
```

For whatever reasons though, it does not work when I try doing it directly from the string.

Thanks for any help with this!
Nic

Comment: It looks like you are putting just one long string into the combo

Comment: I would guess that you have spaces or line breaks in your text file. Try using a regex to "clean" the string: Dim cleanString As String = Regex.Replace(yourString, "[^A-Za-z0-9\-/]", "")

Comment: Thanks @DanielGee ! That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this, I have to assume that the data in the text file is formatted as one line for each piece of data.

There seems to be a couple of issues with your code. `fdcount` is just declared as a string where it should be an array to make it easier to access each line that is read from the file. `fdcount1` has no relationship to `fdcount` - it is a completely separate entity, so the data in fdcount1 is coming from somewhere else.

Rather than the above code, It's easier to use this

```
    Dim fdcount() As String
    fdcount = File.ReadAllLines("SaveData/classdata/classdata2.NIC")
    MessageBox.Show(fdcount(1))
```

Note that `fdcount` is declared as an `Array of String`. The 2nd line does all the opening, reading into the array, and closing of the file.

You can then access each element of the array as shown in the 3rd line.

Comment: Sorry, that fdcount should be fdcount1, that was just a mistake.

Comment: Also, just debugged it, and got this error:                                                        An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Project.exe

Comment: Yes! David Wilson solved it, but he commented, so I cannot give him "Best Answer" or whatever it is called.